# How to open a excel from specific folder

Tags: excel, vba

For example: I have a folder name called TEST. And TEST contain aaa.xlsx, bbb.xlsx, ccc.xlsx,.......,zzz.xlsx 
Now if i enter a file name(aaa.xlsx) in a cell and enter vba button it should display data from aaa.xlsx.

-Folder Name and file names are static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created list of file name is sheet1.

```
Sub DropDown2_Change()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("dropdown").Select
Range("a5:Z1000").Clear
    With Worksheets("dropdown").Shapes("Drop Down 2").ControlFormat
    'MsgBox "ListIndex: " & .ListIndex & vbNewLine & "List value:" & .List(.ListIndex)
    Sheets("dropdown").Range("A3").Value = .List(.ListIndex)
    End With
    currentfile = Sheets("dropdown").Range("a3").Value
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\path\" & currentfile
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Dropdown").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("a5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows(currentfile).Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add a single workbook:

```
Sub openworksheet()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\........\test.xlsx" 'past your file path within " "
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, This will help me. Could you pls share a sample file. This code not working for me. I may be wrong

Comment: Actually folder is static. I will create a drop down of n number of file name. So i prefer fetch with file name.

Comment: I don't want open at same time. Would like to open single and randomly.

Comment: I'm sorry, the output with encoded data. Not working well. And i don't want open all the file at same time. I would like to open specific file only

Comment: well I dont know what is your data structure, can you upload some sample? the code works with my files. Also please see my edit below for an example of loading an individual file that you can build on to sute your need .

Comment: you can add the above to a module and run witha button in your worksheet